# How do I define a turtle in Python without creating a new one?

Tags: python, variables, undefined, turtle-graphics

I am coding a game and am using turtles to import images as this is the only way I know, but I am having a problem where when I try to define my turtle outside of its original function (so that I can use it elsewhere), it creates another turtle with the same name rather than making the first turtle actually perform the 'goto' line. Here is an example of the problem that occurs in my code. (This is not from my actual code, however, the problem is the same and isn't affected by my other code:)

```
import turtle

def example():
    a = turtle.Turtle()

example()
a.goto(100,0)
```

This gives `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. Then when I try to define `a`, like this:

```
example()
a = turtle.Turtle()
a.goto(100,0)
```

the output is of two turtles with only one of them performing the `goto()` command.

Thank you for taking your time to read my post, I am new to coding and this has been bothering me!

Comment: Variables assigned in a function are local to the function. They cease to exist when the function ends and have nothing to do with vars of the same name outside the function . Unless you use a `global a` statement in your example function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because variables inside a function is bound to the functions scope. Basically, if you define the variable `a` inside the function `example()`, the variable only lives inside that function and will die when the function call ends.

If you for instance try and run the following:

```py
def foo():
    bar = 2

foo()
print bar
```

**Output**

```
> NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

This happens because `bar` only lives inside `foo`. You can however use use the `global` statement to bind `bar` to the global scope.

```py
def foo():
    global bar
    bar = 2

foo()
print bar
```

**Output**:

```
> 2
```

This is however not a very good practice. Instead, in your case you could return the object when calling `example` and thus get the object you've created.

```py
import turtle

def example():
    a = turtle.Turtle()
    return a

a = example()
a.goto(100,0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked! I had it fixed before and this was driving me crazy, I will make sure to use this again in the future. I would also like to say that this worked for one of my variables but not another (It must've been an error elsewhere) so I took your advice and defined them outside of the function and it works.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked @OliverPickford. You can always declare variables inside functions and return them at the end of the function to continue its life cycle outside the function. There are a few answers in this thread, so please feel free to mark the answer you feel helped you the most as an accepted answer to bring closure to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're very close.  The one thing I would do is to make sure your python function `example()` returns an object. Right now it returns nothing.  Also, be sure to assign whatever the function returns to a variable. I would try:

```
import turtle

def example():
    a_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    return a_turtle

a = example()
a.goto(100,0)
b = example()
b.goto(50,0)
```

I don't know the turtle package too well, so I'm not sure if there is a way to get multiple turtles to respond with one command, but the above code works for me to get two turtles, `a` and `b` to move.

*Edit*: Also, like other answers say, read up a bit on namespaces and functions.  It'll help to make clear what is accessible where.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your quick response and help! I will also make sure to read up on them.

Answer (score 0):

I read and write lots of Python turtle code and the most common ways I see this situation being handled are:

```
import turtle

def example():
    a.dot()  # do something with the turtle

a = turtle.Turtle()

example()

a.goto(100, 0)
```

Or, just as often:

```
import turtle

def example(t):
    t.dot()  # do something with the turtle

a = turtle.Turtle()

example(a)

a.goto(100, 0)
```

These approaches also reflect that turtles always behave like *global* entities (they're registered on a list inside the turtle library so are never garbage collected.) Creating one inside a function, and not returning it, doesn't make it *local* to the function -- just the pointer to it is local.  The turtle continues to exist *nearly* inaccessible afterward.

Comment: Thank you, I have been having issues with local/global variables recently and your advice has helped me.